# Real differentiability of $f\circ g$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n, B\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $C\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ be open subsets, $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$ such that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ and surjective and $g\circ f:A\to C$ is $C^{\infty}$. Does it follow that $g$ is $C^{\infty}$?

Intuitively, I think it's true, but I'm having trouble formalizing it, since I would have to show that each partial derivative of $g$ exists, which looks complicated.

Answer (score 6):

No, it fails even when all dimensions are 1: for example, consider $f(x) = x^3$, $g(x) = x^{1/3}$.